# cannot import fbconsole, fbconsole install?

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, easy-install

I am trying to use [fbconsole](https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole).

The website say

```
pip install fbconsole
```

But I dont have pip, so I use easy_install fbconsole and fbconsole is installed.

I check Python directory and there is fbconsole-0.3-py2.7.egg file.

I try to import fbconsole, but the error is

```
Internal Server Error
import_string() failed for 'myapp.views.index'. Possible reasons are: - missing __init__.py in a package; - package or module path not included in sys.path; - duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path; - missing module, class, function or variable; Debugged import: - 'myapp' found in 'D:\\PythonProj\\LLL\\myapp\\__init__.pyc'. - 'myapp.views' not found. Original exception: ImportError: No module named fbconsole
```

UPDATE 1: My Project structure is

[image]
which is quite different with your explanation because I am using KAY framework.
I follow your explanation but still fail to import the package.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the `fbconsole` module into your GAE project to make it work.
installing it via `pip` or `easy install` does make it available for your local python but not for the GAE project.

Comment: You'll need to put fbconsole in your application's top-most directory or use a script like this - https://gist.github.com/4632192

Comment: @SeanLynch why would you answer the same thing i did as a comment to my answer?

Comment: I commented so it was clear where to put `fbconsole`, and since putting a lot of libraries at the project root is not always desired, provided a script to allow it to be made available under a 'packages' directory

Comment: you are right only for the simplest case. you can put your modules wherever you want if you import them from the right place after.

Comment: @SeanLynch: in the file,  package_dirs = ["packages"] should be replaced by package_dirs = ["C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"] ?

Comment: @John - No, you would copy the contents of `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` into the `packages` directory at the root of your project.  I updated my gist (https://gist.github.com/4632192) to hopefully better explain this.  Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Also, you can still put your libraries in the packages subfolder and not even use path_fixer.py, but you'll need to fbconsole from the root of your application, so you would use `from packages import fbconsole` instead of `import fbconsole`.  This is what @aschmid00 was saying a few comments back.

Comment: @SeanLynch: Thanks for your help. I still can not import fbconsole and other packages even though I have followed your instruction on gist. I updated my question with folder structure. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

When I `pip install fbconsole` I don't get an `.egg` file, but an `.egg-info` file, which is only metadata, along with the project files `fbconsole.py` and `fbconsole.pyc`.  It appears a source package is the only uploaded format on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fbconsole/0.3), so it appears your issue is you need to copy the `fbconsole.py` file (and optoinally `fbconsole.pyc`, although it will rebuild this file on first access) to your packages directory if you're using my `path_fixer.py` script, or to the root of your project if not.

Here's more info about the differences between `.egg` and `.egg-info` files.

> There are two basic formats currently implemented for Python eggs:
>
> 1. `.egg` format: a directory or zipfile *containing* the project's    code and resources, along with an `EGG-INFO` subdirectory that
>      contains the project's metadata
> 2. `.egg-info` format: a file or directory placed *adjacent* to the    project's code and resources, that directly contains the project's
>      metadata.

http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/doc/formats.txt